# Assembly Iteration

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote the following piece of code, but it's getting the answer wrong. It's supposed to do x^2 but it seems that it iterates one more time than needed:

The result of 1 is 2 // 1+1=2
The result of 2 is 8 // 2+2+2=8

I believe its comparing CX with the ZeroFlag, not the 1 in the first statement. Is that right?

```
pos:
     MOV CX,Number   
    again:  Add Number,AX
            Dec cx
            cmp cx,1
            jg again ; statement no. 1
    JMP DONE
```

Comment: You're adding (Add Number,AX), not multiplying.

Comment: Shouldn't use multiplication or division though..

Comment: What does `AX` contain? Also, your logic is a bit off: you're always doing one addition even if `CX` was <=1 before entering the loop.

Comment: it worked fine.. AX was supposed to contain the value of number.. but it was actually holdin (Number*2) thats why it didn't work..

Comment: x^2 is multiplication not addition.

Comment: x^2 equals [X*X] which means X+X x times :)
2^2 = 2*2 = 2+2 = 4 // 
3^2 = 3*3 = 3+3+3 = 9

Comment: Yeah I know multiplication is addition, this is taught in primary school. I don't know though why would you waste CPU time converting a power to an addition when you have MUL instruction in x86.

Comment: Because I was still at the very basic level maybe :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're sure AX is initialized to zero, the code should work.
Try:

```
MOV Number, AX
```

before the loop starts, but also check that your number is greater than 1 before the loop starts just so that it would not produce wrong results on < 1.

Comment: AX was supposed to contain the value of number.. but it was actually holdin (Number*2) changed 't and worked just fine